# Binary matrix initialization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix, binary, initialization

I have to initialize a matrix (of size *Nx(N-1)*) with *0's* and *1's*, where every time I put a *0* (or *1*) in the [*i*, *j*] position, a *1* (or *0*) is placed in the matrix too, in the [*k*, *j*] position, where *k* is a random row different to *i* (notice that the column is the same).

The condition to satisfy is that there cannot be more than 2 consecutive *0's* or *1's* in the same row.

So, the next matrix would be invalid:

0 1 1

**1 1 1**

1 0 1

0 1 1

And this one would be valid:

0 1 1

1 0 0

1 1 0

0 0 1

Any ideas on how I can implement this initialization? Suppose the matrix starts with *-1's* in it.

Comment: How big could the matrix get?

Comment: 32x31 will be the maximum possible size of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for such a matrix to exist (every (i,j) tuple having a unique opposite (k,j) tuple), N has to be a multiple of 2.

**Step 1** create a fully random (N/2)*(N-1) matrix.

**Step 2** correct mistakes in this matrix, so that every row has no mistakes. With the following algorithm:

```
for row in matrix:
    for i in range(0, len(row) - 2):
        if row[i] == row[i + 1] == row[i + 2]:
            row[i + 2] = 1 if row[i + 2] == 0 else 0
```

**Step 3** For every row, append the inverse row, in order (aka N/2) rows.

```
for row_index in range(N // 2):
    row = matrix[row_index]
    new_row = [0 if x == 1 else 1 for x in row]
    matrix.append(new_row)
```

**Step 4** For every (i, j) generate a p in [0, N), swap (i,j) with (p,j) and see if it contradicts the 3 in a row pattern, if it does, swap them back.

Comment: "where every time I put a 0 (or 1) in the [i, j] position, a 1 (or 0) is placed in the matrix too, in the [k, j] position, where k is a random row different to i (notice that the column is the same)." this is a condition that always has to be satisfied.

Comment: Even after it's corrected. So, after the position [k, j] is determined, [i, j] and [k, j] **has to be** the opposite.